# Include external library jars in jar to mac .app conversion

Tags: java, macos, jar, file-conversion

I am sorry if this question is placed wrong, but considering it is about jars and Java I figured it would probably be the closest to my subject.

I have a Java program of which I have made, this program I am going to distribute for Mac and Windows. To do this for Windows I have used Launch4j, which works without any issues. Now the problem is that when I try to convert the jar into .app for Mac, it doest work, the app just opens and then closes right after. I suppose this is because when converting to Mac .app using Appmaker it doesn't include the external libraries I have used for the program. Because of this I am now wondering how I would add the external libraries to the .app file like I have done on the .exe, where I have just added the .lib folder with all the external library jars into the folder where the .exe is in. 
I have tried adding the .lib folder to the content folder which is created for the .app file, but that doesn't work, I have also tried adding it to the ressource folder within the .app file.

One of the options I have found myself is to combine all external libraries and the actual program .jar file into one. It just seems very difficult and really I don't need it to be just one combined .jar, if it can be included in another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure of Appmaker but can do something like an uber jar, i.e. a single jar that contains all the classes, basically take all the jars unzip them to a signle folder and then jar them up again.

Not sure what you are using to build but maven has a [maven shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) that does exactly this.

Comment: thank you very much for the feedback and input, I am using Netbeans for building the actual program, it has some GUI features. If I were to make an uber jar as you say, when I have build the actual program, I just have to go to the dist folder and then unzip both the actual program jar and all the external jars and then how would I then combine it to one jar again?

Comment: You can use the jar command to create a jar. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html